# Cannot get CheckBox x:Name Error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have checkbox in data grid but its x:name is not accessible in code behind. I have Other x:Names that are accessible but only checkbox I cannot get.
Here is my xaml Code

```
<!--Shift-->

<syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn 
AllowSorting="False"
MinimumWidth="100"
HeaderFontAttribute="Bold"
HeaderText="Shift"
MappingName = "Shift">

<syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<StackLayout
IsVisible="{Binding IsShiftEnabled}"
Orientation="Horizontal">

<CheckBox
x:Name="CheckboxShift"
HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
IsChecked = "{Binding Shift}" 
CheckedChanged="CheckBox_CheckedChanged"
BindingContext="{Binding EmployeeNo}"/>

<Image
Source = "{Binding ShiftIcon}"
HorizontalOptions="End"
VerticalOptions="Start"
Margin="0,3,5,0"
WidthRequest="12"
HeightRequest="12"/>
</StackLayout>

</DataTemplate>

</syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn>
```

And the Code behind is

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(CheckboxShift.Checked)
{
   //Code
 }
```

Comment: It is not recommended to access elements inside a DataTemplate

Comment: then how i can access it?

Comment: Move the StackLayout (`DataTemplate` root) to a separate xaml file. You should be able to access it in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

use the `sender` argument

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var ck = (CheckBox)sender;

  if(ck.Checked)
  {
     //Code
  }
}
```

alternately, learn how to use databinding